# Question about ``concert'' format in Appendix E of TeXbook

Tags: texbook.tex

On p.412 of *TeXbook* there is this text:

> The author has extended these macros to a more elaborate format that includes special features for listing the members of the orchestra and for program notes,
> etc.; in this way it becomes fairly easy to typeset little booklets for concert patrons.
> Such extensions need not be discussed further in this appendix, because they don’t
> illustrate any essentially new ideas.

The fact that this format is even mentioned in *TeXbook* means that it can be useful. So, where to find it?

Comment: I don't think that Knuth ever published it.